# ReRendering page from component not refreshing data properly

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, rerender

I have a page:

```
<page>
<NewFeedPanel />
<FeedListPanel />
</page>
```

The NewFeedPanel has a form for posting a question.
The FeedListPanel displays all the posts.
There's a reRender on the FeedListPanel, so once the post is submitted, the FeedListPanel shows the new post.

After I separate the NewFeedPanel to its own component and call it on the page, the FeedListPanel doesn't refresh with the new post anymore. The reRender is working, because I have a console.log that fires every time I post.
Here's the format of the new component version:

```
<page>
<c:NewFeedPanelComponent />
<FeedListPanel />
</page>
```

Comment: How are specifying the ID of the `<FeedListPanel />` in the component?  Is it possible it has the wrong ID?

Comment: I am passing the outputPanel ID. I don't think it's the problem of it not reRendering, because I added a <script> within the panel I'm reRendering that does alert and it fires every time. Something about having that piece as a component now doesn't let the new content get pulled.

Comment: Does the component use it's own controller?  How are you calling the method that is supposed to get the feed list?

Comment: The component has its own controller and the page has its own controller. The method that gets the feedlist is in the page controller.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to diagnose.  You could try moving the method that gets the FeedList to the component controller.  Maybe that would help?

Comment: Trying making it copy&pasteable and you should get a solution